# Why does Extended Events server_principal_name return NULL sometimes?

Tags: sql-server-2012, extended-events

I have an extended event session setup. This is the definition.

```
CREATE EVENT SESSION [Successful-Logins] ON SERVER
ADD EVENT sqlserver.connectivity_ring_buffer_recorded (
    ACTION ( sqlserver.client_app_name, sqlserver.client_connection_id,
    sqlserver.client_hostname, sqlserver.context_info,
    sqlserver.database_id, sqlserver.server_principal_name,
    sqlserver.session_id, sqlserver.sql_text ) ),
ADD EVENT sqlserver.login ( SET collect_options_text = ( 0 )
    ACTION ( sqlserver.client_app_name, sqlserver.client_connection_id,
    sqlserver.client_hostname, sqlserver.context_info,
    sqlserver.database_id, sqlserver.server_instance_name,
    sqlserver.server_principal_name, sqlserver.session_id,
    sqlserver.sql_text ) ),
ADD EVENT sqlserver.logout (
    ACTION ( sqlserver.client_app_name, sqlserver.client_connection_id,
    sqlserver.client_hostname, sqlserver.context_info,
    sqlserver.database_id, sqlserver.server_instance_name,
    sqlserver.server_principal_name, sqlserver.session_id,
    sqlserver.sql_text ) )
ADD TARGET package0.event_file ( SET filename = N'Successful-Logins' ,
                                  max_file_size = ( 10 ) ,
                                  max_rollover_files = ( 0 ) )
WITH ( MAX_MEMORY = 4096 KB ,
        EVENT_RETENTION_MODE = ALLOW_SINGLE_EVENT_LOSS ,
        MAX_DISPATCH_LATENCY = 30 SECONDS ,
        MAX_EVENT_SIZE = 0 KB ,
        MEMORY_PARTITION_MODE = NONE ,
        TRACK_CAUSALITY = ON ,
        STARTUP_STATE = OFF )
GO
```

My intention is to query sys.fn_xe_file_target_read_file regularly with a filter on server_principal_name. Unfortunately, this field is not always populated. From the same client app and client host, I have some events where server_principal_name is NULL and other where it is populated.

I'm using this query for testing.

```
SELECT  --TOP 10 
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(19),DATEADD(mi, DATEDIFF(mi, GETUTCDATE(), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),
        xevents.event_data.value('(event/@timestamp)[1]','datetime2')),120) AS [timestamp] ,
        xevents.event_data.value('(event/action[@name="session_id"]/value)[1]', 'int') AS [session_id],
        DB_NAME(xevents.event_data.value('(event/action[@name="database_id"]/value)[1]', 'int')) AS [database_id],
        xevents.event_data.value('(event/action[@name="server_principal_name"]/value)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS [server_principal_name],
        xevents.event_data.value('(event/action[@name="client_app_name"]/value)[1]', 'nvarchar(128)') AS [client_app_name],
        xevents.event_data.value('(event/action[@name="client_hostname"]/value)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS [client_hostname]
FROM sys.fn_xe_file_target_read_file
            ('C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.INSTANCENAME\MSSQL\Log\Successful-Logins*.xel',
            NULL,null, null) f
CROSS APPLY (select CAST(event_data as XML) as event_data) as xevents
ORDER BY DATEADD(mi, DATEDIFF(mi, GETUTCDATE(), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),
        xevents.event_data.value('(event/@timestamp)[1]','datetime2')) DESC
```

Comment: Which events are returning NULL?

Comment: Both login and logout. Out of 3387 events only 15 are NOT NULL.

Comment: What is @@VERSION? I tried to repro and both SQL and Windows auth logins populated correctly in all cases. Is there a logon trigger? Are any of these logins coming in through AD group membership without an explicit login name for them? How about contained database users?

Comment: Great questions.

No logon triggers.
No these particular users are all AD logins (non-groups).
No contained database users.

@@VERSION = "Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.5532.0 (X64) 
 Jul 14 2014 15:00:27 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)"

Comment: This appears to only affect our WCF services (.NET 4.5.1 passing through an AG listener). I'm NOT seeing any NULLs for logins using, ".Net SqlClient Data Provider", "DacFX Deploy", "SQLCMD", or "Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio". Many of the successful client apps are using the AG listener as well.

Comment: How is your WCF service connecting? Is it using a domain account or SQL Auth account? Is there a login matching the account, or is it gaining access via a group? Do you get successful results when you check the login with xp_logininfo?

Comment: The service is connecting using a domain account. There is a login matching the account. I receive a valid record when running EXEC xp_logininfo 'DOMAIN\Account'. The permission path column is NULL, however.

Comment: It's funny, four years ago I challenged Derik for a repro. Today I hit it myself (it was a domain user accessing via a group through SSMS) and I'm still not sure how - but I added `username` in addition to `server_principal_name` to the session definition, and then `coalesce` on the output. Haven't hit `NULL` again since (but I'll keep watching).

Answer (score 0):

This question deserves an answer, so cribbing from @Aaron Bertrand's comment (plus my own experience of this today):

This appears to happen when a domain user has access to login because of group membership, rather than directly.

The connecting client/application doesn't appear to matter: Aaron mentions SSMS, but I'm seeing this for SQL Server linked server connections.

In these cases, the true username should be recorded in a different field. Likely ones to capture and check are:

- `username`
- `session_server_principal_name`

If in doubt, configure the XE session to capture all fields that might be relevant, and look at the raw XML for an example record to see where you see a username. You can then combine these for output via `COALESCE()` or similar.

*Side note: strictly, it's not that this field is being recorded as a null, but rather that the XML tag  is not always present in the XE results. The null only appears when you shred the XML results to a columnar format. Noted in case this helps any reader's understanding.*